# Google Sheets: Change the value of a cell if some conditions are met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets, I would like to change the contents of a cell if certain conditions are met.

Given the following table:

```
+---+-----+-------+----+-----+
|   |  A  |   B   | C  |  D  |
+---+-----+-------+----+-----+
| 1 | Bob | Bobby | AU | yes |
| 2 | Sam | Sammy | AU | yes |
| 3 | Tim | Timmy | AU | yes |
| 4 | Jim | Jimmy | AU | yes |
| 5 | Sam | Sammy | KR | no  |
| 6 | Jim | Jimmy | AU | no  |
+---+-----+-------+----+-----+
```

First, I want to check if the value in D is "no".
If it is "no", I want to take the values on the same row in A, B and C and find them in another row.
If I find them, I want to go to that row and change the value of D to a "no".
If I don't find them, I want to do nothing.

Example:
Jim Jimmy AU is "no" in row 6.
A,B,C in row 6 = A,B,C in row 4.
Therefore, I want to change "yes" in row 4 to "no".

Sam Sammy AU is "yes" in row 2.
Sam Sammy KR is "no" in row 5.
A,B,C in row 2 /= A,B,C in row 5 (AU vs KR).
Therefore, I don't change "yes" in row 2.

I have googled extensively and tried combinations of LOOKUP, ADDRESS, FIND, SEARCH, COUNTIF etc but just can't figure this one out.

Is it even possible? I really need it to be possible... ha.
I'm also open to just blanking the "yes" rows all together or deleting them or **something**. I just need to filter out "no"s from the list, ultimately.

Thank you!

Comment: Add [tag:Google-apps-script] tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script for this requirement makes sense because ColumnD cannot contain a value (eg `yes`) and a formula in the same cell. Also if required for more than 'once off'. However with helper columns and an inserted header row simple formulae (E1 and F1 copied down to suit) should work:

[image: SO47427224 example]

`=A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1` creates a key from ColumnsA:C
`=VLOOKUP(E1,G:G,1,0)` checks for the presence of each key in a lookup table
`=filter(E:E,D:D="no")` creates the lookup table

in conjunction with filtering on ColumnD to select `yes` and ColumnF to exclude `#N/A` and manually changing the first `yes` in ColumnD to `no` and copying down.